# Saving on sql using active android not actually saving

Tags: java, android, database, activeandroid

everyone I've using the activeandroid library in android to avoid doing the sql coding but for some reason it isn0t working

Here is my code:

This is my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="AA_DB_Name"
        android:value="knownFiles2.db"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="AA_DB_Version"
        android:value="5"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >



        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

This is MyApplication class

```
    public class MyApplication extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    ActiveAndroid.initialize(this);
}
```

}

This is the Folders model

```
    @Table(name="Folders")
public class Folder extends Model implements Serializable{
@Column(name="Path")
public String path;

@Column(name = "ShowAllImages")
public String showAllImages;

Folder() {
    super();
}

Folder(String path, String showAllImages) {
    super();

    this.path = path;

    this.showAllImages = showAllImages;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Path: "+path+
            " ShowAllImages "+showAllImages;
}
```

}

This is the servers model

```
    @Table(name = "Servers")
    public class Server extends Model implements Serializable{

@Column(name = "Ip")
String ip;

@Column(name = "Folder")
Folder folder;

Server() {
    super();
}

Server(String ip, Folder folder) {
    super();
    this.ip = ip;

    this.folder = folder;
}

@Override
public String toString() {

    return "Ip: "+ip+" Folder: "+folder.toString();
}

public List<Server> getServer() {
    return getMany(Server.class, "Ip");
}
```

}

And this is the code that I'm trying to get working:

```
       Folder folder = new Folder("private/secret/","show-all-images.php");

                folder.save();

                Server server = new Server("192.168.1.191",
                        folder);
                server.save();

                Log.v("MyTag",server.getId()+"");

                Log.v("MyTag",server.toString());

                Log.v("MyTag","Added");

                ArrayList<Server> data = new Select()
                        .all()
                        .from(Server.class)
                        .execute();

                Log.v("MyTag", data.size()+"");
                for (Server serverLoop:data) {
                    Log.v("MyTag", serverLoop.toString());
                }
```

The log should return all the elements in the database, but it doesn't because it says that the size of the arraylist carrying the data is 0

Here is the Log:
          04-09 22:59:30.824  27608-       27608/com.example.mariomarhuendabeltran.photokeeper V/MyTag﹕ 5
04-09 22:59:30.824  27608-27608/com.example.mariomarhuendabeltran.photokeeper V/MyTag﹕ Ip: 192.168.1.191 Folder: Path: private/secret/ ShowAllImages show-all-images.php
04-09 22:59:30.824  27608-27608/com.example.mariomarhuendabeltran.photokeeper V/MyTag﹕ Added
04-09 22:59:30.824  27608-27608/com.example.mariomarhuendabeltran.photokeeper V/MyTag﹕ 0

As you can see the adding is successful, but the list is empty. The 5 reveals that the element just added is the fifth in the database

Help please!!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your models in manifest as well,

in your manifest add this:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="AA_DB_Name"
    android:value="knownFiles2.db"/>

<meta-data
    android:name="AA_DB_Version"
    android:value="5"/>

<meta-data
        android:name="AA_MODELS"
        android:value=".YourModel1, .YourModel2" />
```

I hope that helps.
The other parts of your code seems fine to me

Comment: This isn't working either, but I think I find the solution, just remove the .all() method. But thank you so.much anyway